# Date compare filter using XSLT?

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a "Date Available" column that was initially had a column type of "Single line of text." All values were in the m/dd/yyy format. The following search filter was used without issue:

(number(ddwrt:FormatDateTime($NeedBy,1033,'yyyyMMdd')) >= number(ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@arsDateAvailable),1033,'yyyyMMdd')) or $NeedBy = '')

But the column type had to be changed to "Date and Time" and now this filter doesn't appear to be working. Is this because the column type was changed? How can I modify this filter to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This will convert the date into a number which you can use to compare other dates (that have also been converted this way):

```
ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(@arsDateAvilable)))
```